# What am I doing wrong with my rakefile?

Tags: ruby, rake, testunit

This is the only thing in my rakefile.

```
Rake::TestTask.new do |t|
  t.libs << "test"
  t.test_files = FileList['test/test*.rb']
  t.verbose = true
end
```

When I run rake the output I get is

```
uninitialized constant Rake::TestTask
```

What am I doing wrong?  I want my rake file to run all unit tests that I specify. Any input would be helpful.
Thanks

Comment: Do you have `require rake/testtask` at the top of your rakefile?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What happens if you `require 'rake/testtask'` at the top of the file?